# Pegar ip e nome da maquina de usuário

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando pegar o ip e o nome da maquina de usuário com javascript pois é uma pagina html e css local e está compartilhada com os usuários da rede.

Comment: Vai rodar sua app com nodejs?

Comment: Nativamente em javascript penso que não seja possível fazer isso. Terá de fazer um requisição a algum ficheiro com um script que lhe retorne o ip da maquina. Pode usar php por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Para conseguir obter o nome do host é simples, basta usar a classe **window**, porém para obter o endereço ip faz-se necessário uma requisição http para algum serviço próprio que te responda esse IP ou a um serviço de nuvem que faça esse trabalho como o freegeoip.net.

Obter o nome do host: `window.location.host`

Exemplo em jquery para frazer um a requição e obter o ip:

```
$.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
      console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: Vale comentar na resposta que nome do host é diferente do nome da máquina do usuário, que foi solicitado. Acredito que o nome da máquina do usuário nem seja possível obter com JS.